# How to add callout in picturebox using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to add `WedgeRectCallout` callout on picturebox using C#.

Is there a way to do it?

please refer image using below link to know about the callout.

[image]

In word document, I can do the same using `Spire.Doc` library and writing below code:

```
 ShapeObject Shape1 = para1.AppendShape(30, 50, ShapeType.WedgeRectCallout);
```

Comment: There is no such thing in Winforms, let alone in PictureBox. You can, however, easily achieve the same effect. Either draw the thing over the PBox in the Paint event or maybe into the Image. Or overlay a Label with a Region that has the shape you want. In any case it is a good start to create a GraphicsPath with the outline you need; this can be used for all 3 options..

Comment: If you use a Label you can code the key events to make it interactive ie let the user 'enter' code.. - And the there jusr __might__ be a VisualBasic control/smartShape, but I never touch the stuff..

Comment: Create a `custom control` with combination of Picture Box & a label or any custom shape type for callout and use that.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal example. It creates a `Panel` subclass with a nested `TextBox`.

Note that you can't add controls to a `PictureBox` in the designer. Instead you can put it on top and use the `Nest` function to embed it in the PBox..

(I use a trick to simplify the drawing of the border: since shrinking a `GraphicsPath` is hard and I am too lazy to write out two of them, I draw the border twice and add a little offset. The effect is a shadow effect, which looks rather nice for a cheat..)

Here is the class in action:

[image]

And here is the class code:

```
class WedgeCallout : Panel
{
  public WedgeCallout()
  {
    tb = new TextBox();
    Controls.Add(tb);
  }

  TextBox tb = null;
  GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();

  protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
  {
    tb.Size = new Size(Width - 10, (int)(Height * 0.66));
    tb.Location = new Point(5, 5);
    tb.BackColor = BackColor;
    tb.ForeColor = ForeColor ;
    tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    tb.Text = "Hiho";
    tb.Multiline = true;
    tb.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    tb.Font = Font;
    SetRegion();
    base.OnLayout(levent);
  }

  protected override void OnBackColorChanged(EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnBackColorChanged(e);
    if (BackColor != Color.Transparent) 
        tb.BackColor = BackColor;
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPaint(e);
    if (Tag == null) return;

    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    using(SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(tb.BackColor))
        e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, (GraphicsPath)Tag);
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkGray, 2f))
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, (GraphicsPath)Tag);
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-1, -1);
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(ForeColor, 2f))
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, (GraphicsPath)Tag);
  }

  void SetRegion()
  {
    Rectangle r = ClientRectangle;
    int h = (int)(r.Height * 0.75f);
    if (gp != null) gp.Dispose();
    gp = new GraphicsPath();
    gp.AddPolygon(new PointF[]{   new Point(0,0),
        new Point(r.Width-1, 0),  new Point(r.Width-1, h),
        new PointF(50, h) ,       new Point(0, r.Height-1),
        new PointF(20, h),        new PointF(0, h)});

    Region = new Region(gp);
    Tag = gp;
  }
}
```

You can set the colors and the Font in the designer..

And the `Nest` function:

```
void Nest(Control child, Control parent)
{
    Point p0 = parent.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
    Point p1 = child.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
    child.Location = new Point(p1.X - p0.X, p1.Y - p0.Y);
    child.Parent = parent;
}
```

It is called from the Form where the controls sit: `Nest(wedgeCallout1, pictureBox1);`

Note that to save to callout with the pbox in one image you need to

- **Nest** the callout in the PBox
- Use `pbox.DrawToBitmap`
- Temporarily set the backcolor to transparent

Example:

```
private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Size sz = pictureBox1.ClientSize;
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sz.Width, sz.Height))
    {
        Color old = wedgeCallout1.BackColor;
        wedgeCallout1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
        bmp.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
        wedgeCallout1.BackColor = old;
    }
}
```